# Qt5 icons not showing in Cmake generated executable

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5, qt-creator

I have a Qt5 Project and I'm compiling it with Cmake.

I added a .qr file with the icons.

In QtCreator, I see the icons in Design Mode, but compiling it, it doesn't show them. I tried different changes in Cmake, but I can't find what's wrong. Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.11)

PROJECT (UtilityDICOM)

FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
SET(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

SET(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON) # necessary?

SET(UI_FORMS
    View/UI/mainwindow.ui
)

SET(UI_RESOURCES
    View/Resources/iconos.qrc
)

SET(UI_QT_CXX
    mainwindow.cpp
)

SET(UI_MOC_HEADERS
    mainwindow.h
)

QT5_WRAP_CPP(UI_WRAPPED_MOC_HEADERS ${UI_MOC_HEADERS})
QT5_WRAP_UI(UI_FORM_HEADERS ${UI_FORMS})
QT5_ADD_RESOURCES(UI_RESOURCES_RCC ${UI_RESOURCES})


ADD_LIBRARY(ui_qt ${UI_QT_CXX}
    ${UI_WRAPPED_MOC_HEADERS}
    ${UI_FORM_HEADERS} ${UI_RESOURCES_RCC}
)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(UtilityDICOM WIN32 main.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(UtilityDICOM
    ui_qt
)
QT5_USE_MODULES(UtilityDICOM Core Gui Widgets)
```

I also tried adding ${UI_RESOURCES_RCC} in ADD_EXECUTABLE, with same result.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: did i get it right that the running application is unable to show icons?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I can see them in QTCreator (references inside qrc file are good), but the compiled main window doesn't show them.

Comment: Yes, there is a generated qrc_iconos.cpp. I opened it and the images path is correct. The images exist in a new folder with the same relative path as in original source code. I'll try to pack the source code, I'm just starting. I copied the .ui file from a previous .pro Qt project, nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got it.

In the CMakeLists.txt:

Despite I saw examples where the resources were added inside a TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES,

I added the resources variable inside the ADD_EXECUTABLE:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(UtilityDICOM WIN32 main.cpp ${UI_RESOURCES_RCC})
```

after deleting the target folder and generating again, it worked.

Thanks everybody. Maybe this is helpful to other people.

Comment: Still relevant in Qt6. I had the same issue of my `resources.qrc` just not showing up when I used `set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)` and put the resource file in `add_library`. When I moved the `set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)` to the `CMakeLists.txt` for my executable and put the `resources.qrc` in `add_executable`, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

`qt` uses plugins to handle the image loading.

you application directory should look like

```
<root>
  -myapplication
  -<imageformats>
    -libq* // the actual image plugin you need (if jpg then 'libqjpeg')
```

you can find the `imageformats` under `<qt root dir>/plugins/imageformats`

cheers

Comment: I found the imageformats dir. I just copied that dir and pasted it inside the generated project folder when compiling from CMake, if that's what you're suggesting. But it didn't work.
I think the problem is related with CMake, like it's not linking correctly the icons (it's a images folder next to iconos.qrc file)

Comment: have you build and run the applicaiton from qtcreator to ensure that it is a problem by cmake?

Comment: Yes, I build and run from QtCreator using CMake.

Comment: This is pretty crazy man, qt implicitly does this when using creator, if you do a custom build with cmake or something else you need this folder and it doesn't warn you, it just doesn't show anything. Had me puzzled for a day, all my other resources were working except icons in stylesheets.